# Taylor expansion for a Gaussian integral in terms of the $2$-moment?

Tags: taylor-expansion, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral, smooth-functions

Let $\mu$ be a centered Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^N$ with the covariance matrix $\sigma$.

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$  be some smooth, bounded mapping.

Then, I wonder if it is possible to expand the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} F_l(y)F_k(y) d\mu(y)
\end{equation}
in terms of the entries of $\sigma$? Here, $l,k \in \{1, \cdots, N\}$ denote the components.

Since many even moment of a Gaussian measure is expressible by products of the entries of $\sigma$, I guess there must be a formula. But I cannot find a relevant reference or finish the calculations myself..

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Basically scale the $\mathbb{R}^N$ by $\sqrt{\sigma}^{-1}$ and take Hermite transform.

Comment: @user10354138 could you tell me what you exactly mean by Hermite transform?

Comment: I mean switching the description of $F_k$ to the coefficients in the Hermite expansion of $F_k(y) \sqrt{\frac{d\mu(y)}{dy}}$